# Technical Design document and external agency

Tags: web-development, documentation

My company is recruiting an external agency to do a site redesign/development (agency has not been selected yet).

Regarding the technical design document, should my company produce that document or the agency?

I do not want to be restrictive when it comes to agency's creative process, but at the same time there are standards/technology choices/architecture that I think should be followed.

Comment: It seems to me that the organization doing the technical design should produce the Technical Design document.  That doesn't prevent you from telling them what you'd like to see in it though.

Comment: Both may be viable options. If you have the technical expertise to make the design decisions and will eventually be maintaining it, it seems like it would be best if the things made by the external agency conform to your standards. On the other hand, there's a difference between standards, technology, and architecture and things like the specific detail design decisions made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the engagement model.

If the third party is acting in a staff augmentation capacity, and they are going to bill you per hour no matter what, either side can prepare the tech docs.  Choose the person who has the greatest familiarity with the technology, know the problem domain best, and has the most available time to dedicate to the work.

If the third party is working in a fixed bid capacity, they are going to be responding to a [RFQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_quotation) with a [SOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_of_work) or a work order.  In this case, the third party is going to want to drive the design.  However, if you wish to steer them in a particular direction, you can introduce [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement)s that specify as little or as much of the architectural approach as you wish.